# Yii2: how to change controllerNamespace inside a request

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to change my `Yii::$app->controllerNamespace` if controller class is **not exists**.

I extend UrlRule and put some check that if there is no such class, **switch** `controllerNamespace`.

```
namespace libs\core;

use Yii;
use yii\web\UrlRule;

class Gateway extends UrlRule
{
    public function parseRequest($manager, $request)
    {
        $return = parent::parseRequest($manager, $request);
        if($return) {
            $className = strstr(ltrim($return[0], '/'), '/', true);
            $params = Yii::$app->params;

            if(class_exists($params['controllerNamespace'] . '\\' . ucfirst($className) . 'Controller')) {
                Yii::$app->controllerNamespace = $params['controllerNamespace'];
            } else {
                Yii::$app->controllerNamespace = 'libs\\controllers';
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }
}
```

this method is working in the main request :)

but **nothing** happened when I use `Yii:$app->runAction()` :(

thanks.

and also let me know if there are better ways to have multiply `controllerNamesapce`? (**NOT** using modules)

Comment: Why don't you simply handle the error?

Comment: Why you want to do this? You can do this via Controller Map in config. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html#controller-map